# How does Python's "print" function is working?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm interested how does Python's print function determines what is the string encoding, and how to handle it?

For example I've got the string:

```
str1 = u'\u041e\u0431\u044a\u0435\u043c
print(str1)  # Will be converted to Объем`
```

What is going on under the hood of python?

**Update**
I'm interested in CPython 2.7 implementation of python

Comment: That is probably not dictated by the standard, but left for whoever implements an interpreter to determine...

Comment: Do you mean 2.7? You've used the 3 print function

Comment: @doctorlove Even 2.7 has a print function available via `from __future__ import print_function`, otherwise the above is a print statement - `(str1)` is then just a parenthesized form.

Comment: @doctorlove I tagged it as python-2.7 so yes I mean 2.7

Answer (score 1):

It uses the encoding in `sys.stdout.encoding`, which comes from the environment it's running in.

Comment: could you explain it in more details please

Answer (score 0):

The `u` in front of the string makes a difference.The '`u`' in front of the string values means the string has been represented as unicode. It is a way to represent more characters than normal ascii can manage.

The default encoding for Python source code is **UTF-8**, so you can simply include a **Unicode** character in a string literal.

[More info here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support)